# How to retrieve data from one or more tables that does not have direct relationship with the table of model class

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm forced to change my entire post, since I believe I was not able to make myself clear. Also, I got one answer but I believe it's due to my poor explanation of the problem at the first place that the answer is not very helpful in my case.

Allow me to explain more clearly. This below is my model:

```
class HomeLoanDistributionsDetail extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'HomeLoanDistributionsDetail';
    var $actsAs = array('Logable' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'userKey' => 'user_id',
            'change' => 'list', // options are 'list' or 'full'
            'description_ids' => TRUE // options are TRUE or FALSE
    ));
    var $validate = array(
        'entry_date' => array(
            'rule' => 'date',
            'message' => 'Enter a valid date',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        ),
        'branch_id' => array('numeric'),
        'customer_id' => array('numeric'),
        'loan_amount' => array('numeric'),
        'service_charge' => array('numeric'),
        'security' => array('numeric'),
        'loan_taken_term' => array('numeric'),
        'purpose_id' => array('numeric'),
        'installment_amount' => array('numeric'),
        'installment_service_charge' => array('numeric'),
    );
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'className' => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
            'fields' => 'id,name,fathers_or_husbands_name,credit_card_no,membership_type'
        ),
        'Branch' => array(
            'className' => 'Branch',
            'foreignKey' => 'branch_id',
            'fields' => 'id,name',
        ),
        'HomeLoanCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'HomeLoanCategory',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'fields' => 'id,name',
        )
    );
```

I also have two other Model classes:

1. `LoanGroup` having database table `loan_groups`
2. `LoanGroupsCustomer` having database table `loan_groups_customers`

The most important points:

- `LoanGroupsCustomer` has a field named `customer_id`
- `LoanGroupsCustomer` has another field named `loan_group_id`, which is a foreign key of `LoanGroup`
- `LoanGroup` has a field named `name`. *I want this field to be included in my* `HomeLoanDistributionsDetails` *model.*

So basically, the corresponding SQL query that can get me the correct resultset is this:

```
SELECT D.name AS loan_group, 
CONCAT(B.name,'/',B.fathers_or_husbands_name) AS customer_name_father_husband_Name ,
B.credit_card_no,B.membership_type AS Member_Class,
A.entry_date AS loan_date,
A.loan_amount, 
A.service_charge,
A.security,
A.loan_taken_term,
E.name,
A.installment_amount,
A.installment_service_charge

FROM home_loan_distributions_details A

LEFT JOIN customers B ON A.customer_id = B.id
LEFT JOIN loan_groups_customers C ON B.id = C.customer_id
LEFT JOIN loan_groups D ON C.loan_group_id = D.id
LEFT JOIN home_loan_categories E ON A.category_id = E.id

WHERE A.customer_id = 18

GROUP BY A.id
```

I have absolutely no idea how I can do the following in my model class using the existing `belongsTo` association in my model class:

```
LEFT JOIN loan_groups_customers C ON B.id = C.customer_id
LEFT JOIN loan_groups D ON C.loan_group_id = D.id
```

Note that my `home_loan_distributions_details` table doesn't have any column like `loan_group_id` or `loan_group` that can be directly mapped to the `loan_groups` table as a foreign key. That's the main reason behind my problem.

I tried something like this in the `belongsTo` association part but got SQL error(*naturally, as expected*):

```
'LoanGroup' => array(
            'className' => 'LoanGroup',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
            'fields' => 'id,name'
        ),
```

CakePHP version - 1.2.5, PHP version - 5.2.11, MySQL version - 5.1.36.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The find you've written with the defined associations should return what you have posted above. How are you rendering this information in the view?

Comment: I've amended my comment above

Answer (score 0):

You can run a [sub-query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries), or you can load the model on the fly with `ClassRegistry::init('region');` and call a find first, passing in the foreign key. I'd recommend the first though, as it'd be more efficient.